# Variable not initialized and I can't use null for booleans

Tags: java, compiler-errors, boolean, try-catch

I'm with a little problem here probably is because I cant figure out how to use try and catch.

My method is a bit long but the problem is simple I think.
I'm having the problem of variable not initialized for the input1 input2 and input3 - I cant initialize them because I need the program to return a error in case this variables is not defined and I cant put then on `null` to be able to find this error.

How to proceed?

```
public void print() {
    boolean input1;
    boolean input2;
    boolean input3;
    String gate;
    boolean calc;

    for (String a : operations.keySet()) {
        if (Gate2.contains(operations.get(a).Gate)) {
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input2)) {
                input2 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input2);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = result.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input2)) {
                input2 = result.get(operations.get(a).input2);
            }
            gate = operations.get(a).Gate;
            calc = cc.calc(input1, input2, gate);
            result.put(a, calc);

        }else if (Gate3.contains(operations.get(a).Gate)) {
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input2)) {
                input2 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input2);
            }
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input3)) {
                input3 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input3);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = result.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input2)) {
                input2 = result.get(operations.get(a).input2);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input3)) {
                input3 = result.get(operations.get(a).input3);
            }
            gate = operations.get(a).Gate;
            calc = cc.calc(input1,input2,input3, gate);
            result.put(a, calc);

        }else if ("not".equals(operations.get(a).Gate)) {
            if (inputs.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = inputs.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }

            if (result.containsKey(operations.get(a).input1)) {
                input1 = result.get(operations.get(a).input1);
            }

            gate = operations.get(a).Gate;
            calc = cc.calc(input1, gate);
            result.put(a, calc);
        }

    }

    System.out.format(" Inputs --> ");
    for (String a : inputs.keySet()) {

        int bit2 = inputs.get(a) ? 1 : 0;
        System.out.format("%5s", bit2);
    }
    System.out.format(" Results --> ");
    for (String a : result.keySet()) {

        int bit2 = result.get(a) ? 1 : 0;
        System.out.format("%3s", bit2);
    }
    System.out.format("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using primitive boolean, so you need to initialize it to either true or false. You can use wrapper [java.lang.Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on that, Boolean is effectively tri-state: true, false or null. So you can put

```
Boolean input1 = null;
...
if (input1 == null) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For local variables we need to initialize them before using, while for class/instance variables they are initialized to default values implicitly (null in case of objects)

Answer (score 0):

either use Boolean class which can have true/false/null or use another variable to indicate if they are initialized or not: you can initialize them to false, add another variable isInit and initialize it to false too, once you initialize the variables switch isInit to true, this way you can check if they are initialized using isInit